# ElasticSearch - Indexing and searching nested JSON records where level of nesting of keys vary across JSON documents

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a set of JSON records having similar structure as below:

```
{
     "_root": [
       {
         "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE",
         "Page": 0,
         "Type": "Header3",
         "Child": [
           {
             "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR BUYERS",
             "Page": 0,
             "Type": "Header2",
             "Child": [
               {
                 "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR SELLERS",
                 "Page": 0,
                 "Type": "Header4",
                 "Child": [
                   {
                     "Text": "IMPORTANT INFORMATION",
                     "Page": 0,
                     "Type": "Header5",
                     "Child": [
                       {
                         "Text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS",
                         "Page": 0
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ],
     "_text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS"
    }
    {
     "_root": [
       {
         "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE",
         "Page": 0,
         "Type": "Header2",
         "Child": [
           {
             "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR BUYERS",
             "Page": 0,
             "Type": "Header4",
             "Child": [
               {
                 "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR SELLERS",
                 "Page": 0,
                 "Type": "Header5",
                 "Child": [
                   {
                     "Text": "IMPORTANT INFORMATION",
                     "Page": 0,
                     "Type": "Header6",
                     "Child": [
                       {
                         "Text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS",
                         "Page": 0
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ],
     "_text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS"
    }
    {
     "_root": [
       {
         "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE",
         "Page": 0,
         "Type": "Header1",
         "Child": [
           {
             "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR BUYERS",
             "Page": 0,
             "Type": "Header2",
             "Child": [
               {
                 "Text": "IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR SELLERS",
                 "Page": 0,
                 "Type": "Header3",
                 "Child": [
                   {
                     "Text": "IMPORTANT INFORMATION",
                     "Page": 0,
                     "Type": "Header4",
                     "Child": [
                       {
                         "Text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS",
                         "Page": 0
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ],
     "_text": "THIS OFFERING IS AVAILABLE ONLY TO INVESTORS"
    }
```

I store such records in ElasticSearch and then I need to search for particular keyword text in each Json record. The search keyword may or may not be present in certain 'nested' Json structures. In other words following query returns a result but not the one after this:

```
{
  "query": { "match": {"_root.Child.Child.Child.Child.Text" : "OFFERING" } }
}
```

This does not return result:

```
{
  "query": { "match": {"_root.Child.Child.Child.Text" : "OFFERING" } }

}
```

How do I enable search to return correct results when the level of nesting as well as the key identifiers are different across JSON documents ? Similarly during indexing I don't have a fixed mapping to define per record.

> NOTE: I am re-posting this question (after refining) as a similar
>   question was posted earlier by my colleague but that got closed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your sample docs, it makes sense that the 2nd query doesn't return anything -- there is no `OFFERING` under that given path!

Observation: your `Child` sub-objects all tend to contain one and only one child. So flattening the whole thing should not be too difficult. You'll still retain the `Type` identifiers etc but your structure will be easier to work with, plus your query's complexity will be reduced to 1 match query and possibly `"_root.children.Type": "Header6"` or similar...

Suboptimal solution: you can do the following until you reach the deepest level:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_root.Child.Text": "OFFERING"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_root.Child.Child.Text": "OFFERING"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_root.Child.Child.Child.Text": "OFFERING"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_root.Child.Child.Child.Child.Text": "OFFERING"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Flattening the JSON is an alternative. On the other hand I would assume there are no in-built ways of searching through a nested structure in ES.

Comment: There is. It’s called the nested datatype. Look it up. But it’s not necessarily what you aspire to do. I really recommend flattening your JSON and making the individual array objects “nested.“

Answer (score 0):

How about using muti match

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "OFFERING",
            "fields": ["_root.Child.Text", "_root.Child.Text.Text", "_root.Child.Text.Text.Text"]
        }
    }
}
```